# Single side signal source

Tags: arduino

I want to know if there is such a thing exist as single sided signal. For example, wifi router transmits data all around the router in all directions. Same as Bluetooth. Is there something that only sends signal 180 degrees to one side.

I want to make an arduino project that can detect if the person is behind the wall or in front of the wall So if the person receives signal, it means he or she is behind the wall. Else, he or she is on the other side of the wall.

It may sounds strange to you. Hope you get what I mean. And by the word signal, it can really be any signal from BT to wifi. Is there a name for this kind of thing?

Comment: I think that it doesn't is in technology. You may search a directional antenna.

Comment: What if you were to do it optically? RF likes to go through walls, but IR has a devil of a time getting through plasterboard.